# Admitting to a different crime as one's alibi?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law

Mark is accused of a Murder committed between 1pm-2pm on March 10th. However, at that time, Mark 100% has an alibi for something else he was doing (which isn't exactly legal).
For example

1. Mark was doing meth in front of his buddy Bob
2. Mark was beating his wife Wendy

What is Mark supposed to do? Admit to his other crime as an alibi to get him off the hook for what he's accused of? If one admits to other crimes during a trial, will that get added on to the crimes he's being tried for? Or will Mark get acquitted for murder, but immediately be put on trial for the other crime he admitted to? Or what?

My gut tells me that Mark's best course of action is to weigh the consequences for what he's convicted of against what he would be admitting to. Is that right?

Comment: If Mark was with Bob, and Bob can vouch for him, what has 'doing meth' got to do with it? If he was with Wendy, it is known that a 'co-dependent' partner may not admit to being beaten, so again, what has the crime to with the alibi?

Comment: @WeatherVane please try to answer the "intent" of the question, not the "letter" of the question. Meth was a random imperfect example. The point is that Mark was doing something else illegal at the time (like another murder, or what have you). And using that as an alibi is tantamount to admitting to another crime.

Comment: Then choose some realistic scenarios, please. You are asking for advice as to what Mark should do. He was 'hanging out' with the alibi.

Comment: What credible and reliable evidence is there for the murder charge?

Comment: This would be a good time to call for a lawyer.

Comment: a better example might be on camera with a ski mask robbing a bank in a city 2 hours away...they would still want to prove it actually was you though since you could be just saying that to get reduced prison time.

Comment: Doing meth is not illegal. Selling meth is illegal.

Comment: Presumably you wouldn't use *another murder* as your alibi if you're trying to get off from one murder.  "Why, your honor, I couldn't have murdered John between 1 and 2, I was busy murdering Steve across town at that hour!"  Not exactly the best strategy.  You'd hope the alibi-crime is a lesser one than the original crime you're being accused of...

Comment: Assume that Mark is on probation and the terms of Mark's probation require him to be in City X at all times.  Assume from publicly available information that it is known that both Bob and Wendy were well outside City X at that time.  If they testified that they were with Bob then a good prosecutor can prove that Mark was outside City X and thus violated probation.

Comment: Ideally Mark's should not think about it.  It is the prosecution's burden to prove Mark's guilt and if Mark was outside City X then hopefully the case should fail.  However, copping to a minor crime in return for a guaranteed not guilty on a major crime seems like a good trade.  Mark should consult a lawyer on this one.

Comment: Colin Farrell actually went through exactly this situation. The fact that the journal his friend kept said they were doing ecstasy doesn't seem to have caused a problem for him https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2015/06/true-detective-colin-farrell-attempted-murder

Comment: @NeilMeyer in most places, possession of illicit substances is... illicit. *Doing* the drugs may technically not be illegal, but you tend to need to at least temporarily possess them to do them. Possession of "drug paraphernalia" (pipes, needles etc) is also illegal in many places.

Comment: This is one of several reasons taking the fifth doesn't mean you're guilty: "where were you during the murders?" "I plead the fifth" (because the real answer is robbing a convenience store or something). Cartoon version, obviously.

Comment: @fectin but if you plead the fifth then you haven't presented evidence of an alibi.

Comment: I see this not as anything to do with Law but rather as some kind of Philosophy… Does anyone think I'm mistaken?

Answer (score 17):

### “Anything you say can be used against you in court.”

Is what the police say in the USA.

“You are not obliged to say or do anything unless you wish to do so, but whatever you say or do may be used in evidence. Do you understand?” is what they say in New South Wales.

“You do not have to say anything, but it may harm your defence if you do not mention, when questioned, something which you later rely on in court. Anything you do say may be given in evidence.” is what they say in England and Wales.

And so on.

Whether Mark wants to mention that he was robbing a bank on the far side of town at the time is entirely up to him. If he does, and that can be verified it’s likely the murder charges will be dropped and armed robbery charges will be brought instead.

Note that in many jurisdictions, if the defence intends to use an alibi defence, the prosecution must be told about it at a very early stage or it can’t be used at all.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143157/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-admitting-to-a-different-crime-as-ones-alibi); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 15):

It's less about what you are doing, than who you are doing it with.  Because the character of that person, and/or material evidence, is what the court will evaluate.

You can also establish the alibi and then plead the 5th on exactly what you were doing.

"What were you doing with Nick, there on the security camera of the truck dock area?"
"Smoking."
"That doesn't look like cigarettes. What were you smoking?"
"I refuse to answer on the grounds that the answer might tend to incriminate me."
(Jury chuckles)
And that's the end of that.

Let's have some fun, though...
"Come now, surely you realize marijuana is legal in this state."
"Not Federally!"
(Judge and attorneys laugh)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the jurisdiction, the defendant can *[proffer](https://pappalardolaw.com/2021/09/proffer-criminal-negotiation-tactic/)* information to the Prosecution on an unattributable basis via their solicitor. In this instance, the Prosecution would be told in no uncertain terms that the defendant has a cast-iron alibi but that they don't want to share the information because it could incriminate them in a different crime.

Normally this would be posed as a hypothetical, given in an [off-the-record conversation](https://www.robertbonsib.com/articles/proffer-letter-agreements-watch-your-step-a-discussion-of-practical-issues-regarding-proffer-letter-agreements-by-robert-c-bonsib-esq/) to avoid it being considered a direct confession, or the prosecution could offer [limited immunity from prosecution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_immunity) based on the evidence provided.

*"Hypothetically speaking, my client could have an alibi that could cause them to be charged with a different crime, but which the confession of would absolutely prove that they weren't at the scene of the murder, and hence blow a hole in the very expensive homicide case you're planning to present to the court. Would that knowledge, hypothetically speaking, be of interest to you?"*

Comment: Note that in the UK this information would typically be part of an *informal and unattributable conversation* between the CPS and the defendant's solicitor rather than being part of any formal process, since the CPS is largely independent of the police and can't normally direct them to investigate additional crimes

Answer (score 2):

### Merely being somewhere isn't usually a crime

All Mark has to prove is that he *was* somewhere else than the murder scene when it was committed. Proving the presence in a certain place at a certain time often can be done without revealing what exactly was being done in there.

If/when pressed what he was doing there, invoking the 5th will be sufficient and, provided that the proof of being there is itself strong enough, it won't create any negative consequences.

Answer (score -3):

So Jack was murdered, Mark had an excellent motive but says he committed a bank robbery just at that time. That may be the truth or a lie.

You might get convicted for the robbery because you admitted it. You might get convicted for murder because your alibi isn’t believed and there is a motive and other evidence (innocent people get convicted at times).

I don’t know if you can get convicted twice. Obviously you can’t have done both crimes. But each one could be proven beyond reasonable doubt independently.